# How to prevent Visual Studio from adding folder names to namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

My project is called `SomeImportantProject.API`.  I have a folder in my project called `foo`.  When I create a class in that folder, it creates it with the name of the folder `SomeImportantProject.API.foo`.

How can I tell VS to simply use the default namespace for newly created classes?

Comment: Anytime I've created a new `class` file, it has always taken the main `namespace` for the overall project. Is this not the behaviour you're experiencing?

Comment: Any extension you may be using? ReSharper, for instance?

Comment: @ZacharySchroeder That answer is from a decade ago. I was hoping something changed.

Comment: @JonathonChase I thought so too.  I've disabled Resharper.  I believe this has always been the default behavior.

Comment: @AngryHacker I believe your options are the same as they were a decade ago. I believe ReSharper lets you add on new templates pretty easily, it shouldn't be too much work to create a class template that follows your namespace requirements.

Comment: To add onto that, there is a macro provided in ReSharper's templating language, `getDefaultNamespace()`, that can be used as the backing value for a `%NAMESPACE%` variable in a template. This will get you the behavior you desire.

Comment: Resharper lets you set a property on the folder called "Namespace Provider".  Set it to false.